# Metro style gui c++ library without winrt?

Tags: c++, user-interface, microsoft-metro

Is there a cross platform gui library  that emulate metro style look ?
if not, i wonder if you guys can provide me with a cross platform gui library that is customizable.
i tried SFGUI, its good but still in development and very bugy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind switching to another language, I suggest the C# and WPF that allows such customizations.

If you want to stick to C++ try the ones by Embarcadero C++Builder and their Firemonkey API(Its cross platform too) or my favorite Qt from Nokia

My other suggestion would be to use a Webkit control and build the metro style UI in HTML/CSS/Javascript instead.

There are many ways to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks very much it would be nice to use html/js in c++ ui

Comment: Qt has a webkit widget you can use for free and its customizable too @user1748906